# How to use clEnqueueWriteBufferRect in OpenCL

Tags: buffer, opencl

I want to use `clEnqueueReadBufferRect` in OpenCL. To do it, I need to define the `region` as one of its passing arguement. But there is a inconsistency between references of OpenCL
In online [reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBufferRect.html), it is mention that

> The (width, height, depth) in bytes of the 2D or 3D rectangle being read or written. For a 2D rectangle copy, the depth value given by region [2] should be 1.

but in the [reference book](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/opencl-1.2.pdf), page 77, it is mentioned that

> region defines the (width in bytes, height in rows, depth in slices) of the 2D or 3D rectangle being read or written. For a 2D rectangle copy, the depth value given by region [2] should be 1. The values in region cannot be 0

but unfortunately, none of those guides worked for me and I should provide region in (width in columns, height in rows, depth in slices), otherwise, when I defined them as byte not rows/columns, I got the error `CL_INVALID_VALUE`. Now which one is correct?

```
    #define WGX 16
    #define WGY 16
    #include "misc.hpp"


    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    int i;
    int n = 1000; 
    int filterWidth = 3;
    int filterRadius = (int) filterWidth/2;
    int padding      = filterRadius * 2;
    double h = 1.0 / n;


    int width_x[2];
    int height_x[2];

    int deviceWidth[2];
    int deviceHeight[2];  
    int deviceDataSize[2];

    for (i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
    {
        set_domain_length(n, n, height_x[i], width_x[i], i);
    }

    float* x = new float [height_x[0]    * width_x[0]];

    init_unknown(x,             height_x[0], width_x[0], 0);

    set_bndryCond(x, width_x[0], h);

    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);

    assert(platforms.size() > 0);
    cl::Platform myPlatform = platforms[0];

    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    myPlatform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);

    assert(devices.size() > 0);

    cl::Device myDevice = devices[0];
    cl_display_info(myPlatform, myDevice);
    cl::Context context(myDevice);

    std::ifstream kernelFile("iterative_scheme.cl");

    std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(kernelFile), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));

    cl::Program::Sources sources(1,std::make_pair(src.c_str(),src.length() + 1));
    cl::Program program(context, sources);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, myDevice);

    deviceWidth[0]    = roundUp(width_x[0], WGX);
    deviceHeight[0]   = height_x[0];  
    deviceDataSize[0] = deviceWidth[0] * deviceHeight[0] * sizeof(float);

    cl::Buffer buffer_x;
    try
    {
        buffer_x = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,  deviceDataSize[0]);

    } catch (cl::Error& error)
    {
        std::cout << "     ---> Problem in creating buffer(s) " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "     ---> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    cl::size_t<3> buffer_origin;
    buffer_origin[0] = 0;
    buffer_origin[1] = 0;
    buffer_origin[2] = 0;

    cl::size_t<3> host_origin;
    host_origin[0] = 0;
    host_origin[1] = 0;
    host_origin[2] = 0;

    cl::size_t<3> region;
    region[0] = (size_t)(deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float));
    region[1] = (size_t)(height_x[0]);
    region[2] = 1;

    std::cout << "===> Start writing data to device" << std::endl;
    try
    {
        queue.enqueueWriteBufferRect(buffer_x, CL_TRUE, buffer_origin, host_origin, region,
                                    deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float), 0, width_x[0] * sizeof(float), 0, x);

    } catch (cl::Error& error)
    {
        std::cout << "     ---> Problem in writing data from Host to Device: " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "     ---> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    // Build the program  
    std::cout << "===> Start building program" << std::endl;

    try
    {
        program.build("-cl-std=CL2.0");
        std::cout << "     ---> Build Successfully " << std::endl;
    } catch(cl::Error& error)
    {
        std::cout << "     ---> Problem in building program " << std::endl;
        std::cout << "     ---> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        std::cout << "     ---> " << program.getBuildInfo<CL_PROGRAM_BUILD_LOG>(myDevice) << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    std::cout << "===> Start reading data from device" << std::endl;
    // read result y and residual from the device 
    buffer_origin[0] = (size_t)(filterRadius * sizeof(float));
    buffer_origin[1] = (size_t)filterRadius;
    buffer_origin[2] = 0;

    host_origin[0] = (size_t)(filterRadius * sizeof(float));
    host_origin[1] = (size_t)filterRadius;
    host_origin[2] = 0;

    // region of x
    region[0] = (size_t)((width_x[0]  - padding) * sizeof(float));
    region[1] = (size_t)(height_x[0] - padding);
    region[2] = 1;

    try
    {
        queue.enqueueReadBufferRect(buffer_x, CL_TRUE, buffer_origin, host_origin,
            region, deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float), 0, deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float), 0, x);
    } catch (cl::Error& error)
    {
        std::cout << "     ---> Problem reading buffer in device: "  << std::endl;
        std::cout << "     ---> " << getErrorString(error) << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }

    delete[] (x);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post your relevant code, I don’t think anyone will be able to help you otherwise.

Comment: the code is so large, that's why I did not include it in the question. But the question is not about the code, but inconsistency in references of OpenCL.

Comment: Except you say that your interpretations of neither of the 2 pieces of documentation work - so it’ll be pretty important to determine whether it’s perhaps your interpretation that’s wrong, rather than the documentation itself. Hence, code (even distilled down to just the buffer/image creation and rect read enqueuing calls and the specific argument values you are passing to them) is probably going to be important.

Comment: For what it’a worth, my understanding is that the region is specified in the same format as the offset arguments.

Comment: @pmdj I added the code, thanks for your helps anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The online reference link you provided says:

> region
>
> The (width in bytes, height in rows, depth in slices) of the 2D or 3D rectangle being read or written. For a 2D rectangle copy, the depth value given by region[2] should be 1. The values in region cannot be 0.

This is consistent with what you quoted later as "reference book". That's because your first link points to OpenCL 2.0 while the second link to 1.2.

The inconsistency you mention exist between online manual of 1.2 and the PDF of 1.2, but the online manual of 2.0 is consistent with the PDF. So i assume it was a bug in 1.2 online manual which was fixed in 2.0

> otherwise, when I defined them as byte not rows/columns

What's a "column", and how is it different from bytes ?

The "elements" of buffer rect copy are always bytes. If you're reading/writing a 1D rect from a buffer, it simply transfers `region[0]` bytes. The reason why the API has "rows" and "slices" is because if using 2D/3D regions, you can have padding between data; but you can't have padding between elements in a 1D region.

Answer (score 1):

I found out what is the reason of the problem, that's according to the online [reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueWriteBufferRect.html)

> CL_INVALID_VALUE if host_row_pitch is not 0 and is less than region[0].

so `enqueueWriteBufferRect` should change as follow:

```
queue.enqueueWriteBufferRect(buffer_x, CL_TRUE, buffer_origin, host_origin, region,
                            deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float), 0, deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float), 0, x);
```

which means `host_row_pitch = deviceWidth[0] * sizeof(float)` instead of `host_row_pitch = width_x[0] * sizeof(float)`.